# Why cloning canvas? Need explanation on tutorial

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, 2d

I've followed tutorial here: http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/using-tiled-and-canvas-to-render-game-screens to create Tiled map on cavas. I've made some improvements to the solution, but rendering stuff remained the same:

```
var self = this,
    layer = self._canvas.canvas.cloneNode( false );
    layer = layer.getContext( "2d" );
```

Basically, I have somewhere reference to canvas HTML, and here I'm cloning it (just like in tutorial). Next I made some logic and draw tile on that clone:

```
layer.drawImage( ... );
```

Finally after whole drawing tiles is over, the clone is painted on main canvas:

```
self._canvas.drawImage( layer.canvas, 0, 0 );
```

My question is why? When I did same algorithm not on layer, but main canvas instead, rendered image was the same. Is there some logic behind it? Only thing that came to my mind is that we can somehome prevent rendering `layer`, on catched error, to `canvas`. Tutorial meantion only about `we’ll set up a scratch canvas to render to for a slight performance improvement`

Comment: Using a backbuffer is unnecessary when you put your drawing code into [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame4). When you do that, the browser will take care of that. It also has other advantages, like not wasting CPU time with drawing when the tab with your canvas isn't visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're drawing on a back buffer. This prevents the browser from trying to render the canvas to screen while drawing, and aside from the potential performance improvement also prevents potential flickering. (This applies mostly to double buffering, but this method is quite similar)

[About buffering and canvas](http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2010/09/accelerated-game-programming-with-html5-and-canvas/)

Comment: Thanks for interesting tutorial, now I get it

Answer (score 2):

A) As the scratch layer is memory-only there is no need for the browser to try to update the content for each monitor refresh - it is draw once only to the main canvas which then is updated in whole.

B) If you moved things around (which is typical when tiling) using drawImage() with offset/clipping and to itself, the browser does not have to create a temporary bitmap, copy the content over, then copy back to a different position, and finally destroy the temporary bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot mark 2 answers as correct, yours was helpful too, thanks!

Comment: @kamil no problem, the important things is that your problem got solved :-)